# Display JDateChooser in JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane, jdatechooser, jcalendar

I want to display a `JDateChooser` component inside an Option pane depending on some selection from the user.
The point is that I tried getting the `JDateChooser` the way I want it to appear using next code:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, new JDateChooser(),"Start date", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I tried with different kinds of `JOptionPane` variants but I can't figure out how to get this done, the user must be able to select the date and confirm by clicking a button so that I can retrieve that date and use it as a `String`.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Text", "More Text", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

So that in that way I can get the selected date.
I'm working with jcalendar-1.4.jar

Comment: Here is an example of how you can retrieve the results of your dialog inline: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/dialogs/ParamDialog.java

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is something similar to what I was trying to achieve but in this case I needed to replace the input text element with the JDateChooser, look at the answer a managed out, it may be helpful for you in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally reached a solution that worked for me. I stared creating separately a DateChooser and a String and put them together in an Object array, then pass the object as argument for the JOptionPane.

```
JDateChooser jd = new JDateChooser();
String message ="Choose start date:\n";
Object[] params = {message,jd};
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,params,"Start date", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

In order to get the date once the user clicks the "OK" button in the JOptionPane  I implemented a SimpleDateFormat.

```
String s="";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
s=sdf.format(((JDateChooser)params[1]).getDate());//Casting params[1] makes me able to get its information
```

That implementation solved the problem the way I wanted, I hope you guys find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
JDateChooser jd = new JDateChooser();
String message ="Choose start date:\n";
Object[] params = {message,jd};
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, params, "Start date", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE) == 0) { 
    System.out.println("Picked date="+jd.getDate().toString());
    //I dont need to cast to a jdatechooser, i only take the date
    //start the chooser with todays date in case you want using jd.setCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
}
```